# Facelets without JSF

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, servlets, facelets

I'm finishing on learning the Java language and looking to write very small web applications, since Facelets seems to be the replacement for JSP, and JSF seems overkill for small web apps, can I just learn Facelets and use it without the whole JSF stack? or should I just go with JSP for this small web apps?

Comment: Would you like to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095397/what-is-the-difference-between-jsf-servlet-and-jsp/2097732#2097732) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files/3180202#3180202) questions?

Comment: I read those but they don't really say if facelets can be use as a standalone technology.

Answer (score 6):

It *can* be used without JSF. Just map the `FacesServlet` on an URL pattern of `*.xhtml` in `web.xml` and do **not** declare

```
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
```

in any Facelet template. It actually don't harm to declare them, but this way you won't "accidentally" use them. You can as good write plain HTML in it and submit the form to a plain servlet and have the servlet forward/redirect to a Facelet.

You only need to keep in mind that with a servlet you end up with much more boilerplate code for gathering the request parameters, converting/validating them, maintaining and updating the model values, invoking the business actions, while all this repeated boilerplate code is unnecessary with a fullworthy JSF managed bean.

Also, you can't use Facelets with request based MVC frameworks which have only JSP taglibs available, like Struts, Spring MVC, etc.

Comment: Well you still need the whole jsf jar isn't it? Also, when f: and h: is not used, what templating options are left to the developer? Isn't ui considered as a part of jsf for example?

Comment: Why did you say do not declare xmlns:f and :h only? And what can you do without using these tags in a facelets page? Only el is available then?

Comment: No I mean why did not you say "do not declare ui:" as well? Why did you say do not declare f: and h: only?

Answer (score 0):

Facelets is developed for the need of JSF and as so is dependent on JSF. If you need templating for JSP simply use <@import>,  or more advanced library as [Apache Tiles](http://tiles.apache.org/).